# In ConEmu, is there a way to create shortcuts to frequent ssh sessions?

Tags: ssh, conemu

I connect to several different SSH servers throughout the day. In OSX iTerm, you can simply press CMD+O to open all of the saved profiles and connect to those servers very quickly.

I have not found a way in ConEmu to setup any type of "favorites". From my research, it looks like that might just be a task in ConEmu, but I haven't found a specific answer.

Comment: What do you ask? ConEmu is not a ssh client, isn't it? So how do you imagine that list of "favorites", if ConEmu does even know what is it "favorite"? Use tasks!

Answer (score 0):

Install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) which includes a few utilities.

Then in ConEmu create a new task.

The command for your new task will be:

""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"  -exec "ssh user@XXX.XXX.XX.XX""

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that worked for me. It is better git bash before than powershell or cmd because with git bash you can pass prefix for tmux (ctrl+spacebar) than in others you can't do it.

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -l -i -c "ssh user@remote_ip_address"
```

Of course you have to add this line in startup-> Tasks and create a new task. You need to have installed git bash